# Solving two ODEs that reference each other

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, induction

I'm an engineer not a mathmatician. I'm trying to learn the maths as I work through an interesting problem I'm working on. I don't know how to proceed because I don't even know which area of maths I need to solve the following ODEs. The problem is they keep referencing each other in a recursive manner.

$$\frac{dq(t)}{dt} = \frac{W(t)}{ \alpha + q(t) }$$
$$\frac{dW(t)}{dt} = \frac{1}{\alpha + q(t)}$$

Note $\alpha$ is a constant and $q(0) = 0$ and $W(0)$ will be some constant e.g. 2.

I cannot solve the ODE by separation of variable because I can't integrate the functions as they keep expanding each other recursively.

I would very much like to learn how to solve the problem not just the solution to this problem. If you could suggest to me where to study next please. At the moment it reminds me of induction but I'm not sure if that applies to continuous systems.

Thank-you very much in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Take the quotient of both equations to get $dq=WdW$ or $q=\frac12W^2+C$. The constant $C$ depends on the solution, but is constant along each solution. Now insert into the second equation and solve
$$
(α+C+\tfrac12W^2)dW=dt
$$
This gives an implicit cubic equation for $W$.

Comment: Thanks, very clever!